# How do I test if a string begins with a vowel using an iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I have written a program using an iterator for the first time. I have an array list of strings and I have printed them using the hasNext and next method. I am now trying to go backwards using the previous method and while doing so I am suppose to check each element and if it starts with a vowel I nedd to delete it from the list. Here is the piece of code that I am having trouble with.

```
while (iterator.hasPrevious())
      {
         String s = iterator.previous();
         if (s.startsWith("a"))
         {
            iterator.remove();
         }   
         System.out.print(" "+ s);
      }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well what **is** the problem? Stack traces? Undesired results?

Comment: I tried, charAt(0), i've tried, startsWith(). It will not check and remove appropriate strings. I can't figure out the right code.

Comment: Don't forget that in terms of code, "a" and "A" aren't the same thing. If you want to remove Strings starting with a vowel, you have to account for both the uppercase and lowercase versions of them.

Comment: @JonK `remove()` always removes the last element that was returned by the iterator. It doesn't matter whether you're iterating forwards or backwards.

Comment: @DavidConrad So it does - thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
String testString = ... // Iterator String 
if (vowels.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(testString.charAt(0))) != -1) {
    ... // Start char is vowel
}
```

Comment: Can we add upper case also to the vowels ?

Comment: I like this, add Character.toLowerCase(char)

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a `String` starts with a vowel, you can use regular expressions.

For instance:

```
String[] input = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
for (String s: input) {
    System.out.printf("\"%s\" starts with a vowel? %b%n", s, s.matches("(?i)^[aeiouy].*$"));
}
```

**Output**

```
"abc" starts with a vowel? true
"def" starts with a vowel? false
"ghi" starts with a vowel? false
```

**In your case...**

The method `startsWith` only takes a literal, so it's not what you want.

Instead, you could use a constant `Pattern` in your class, such as:

```
static final Pattern STARTS_WITH_VOWEL = Pattern.compile("^[aeiouy]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Then in your loop, you could use:

```
if (STARTS_WITH_VOWEL.matcher(s).find()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How about a case insensitive matching? `s.toLowerCase().matches(...)` would do the trick.

Comment: @GurusharanS was thinking just the same... just edited!

Comment: As this seems to be something of an academic exercise, perhaps an explanation of what the regular expression does would be useful?

Comment: And `%n` is probably a typo - should've been `\n` :P

Comment: @GurusharanS nope. That's a new line in `String` formats (although `\n` works just as well).

Answer (score 1):

A readable way to do it would be to have a list of all the vowels

```
Collection<Character> vowels = new HasSet<~>();
vowels.add('a');
vowels.add('e');
vowels.add('i');
vowels.add('o');
vowels.add('u');
```

Then what you could do is

```
if (vowels.conatins(Character.toLowerCase(s)))
{
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: A `HashSet` would be more efficient. Maybe `Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u'))`?

Comment: Those we will be learning next week. You're probably right though!

Answer (score 0):

just change the if to include more conditions

if (s.startsWith("a") || if (s.startsWith("A"))...)

Comment: The string that i'm checking is "aaa". So something else is wrong or it would've deleted "aaa". I was just trying out code and if I could get that to work I was going to add more conditions.

Comment: @Mena first get it working, then make it elegant? if he hasnt figured out if statements, what makes you think he ll understand regex matching?